# How to see the rest of screen and add more text

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, scrollviewer

Tell me how can i see the rest of the screen in my xaml? I added text block with height 2000 pixels, how can I see the rest? And, what's going on, when I add scrollviewer in content section and my text block automatically goes to the left upper corner? And, in my xaml i see where the text is centered, it looks ok, but in emulator text is in single line. How to repair it?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="Excercises.Weider_s_six"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF1FB0DB">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Weider's six" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" FontSize="64" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                <TextBlock Height="2000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="TextBlock1" Text="Weider 6 pack Training is a perfect exercise for flat stomach.
    This easy training programme has many advantages.
    It's perfect for beginners and for experts – exercises are easy and begin with the basic level, so every beginner can use them but they get more complicated pretty fast so advanced sportsmen can also be interested in them.
    It helps not only carve your muscles but also burn fat – during the exercise you not only use your abdominal rectus but you also move your legs and arms. It is also because W6 puts pressure on the number of repetitions. It carves your muscles but also burns fat. You can train W6 for about 40 minutes without taking any breaks – you use up all glycogen in blood and start burning the fat.
    It is easy – it is a really easy training set which you can train almost anywhere. All you need is flat ground.
    It gives excellent results – if you want to have a flat stomach W6 is designed just for you. You can see the first effects after just a week and after a whole series it is really impressive.
    How to do Weider 6

    Starting Position

    Lay flat on the ground, hands along the body.
    1 – exercise 1

    Lift your right leg and bend your knee to right angle angle
    Lift your upper torso to contract abdominal muscles and hold the lifted knee with your hands.
    Hold still for 3 seconds.
    Return to the starting position.
    Repeat the exercise with the other leg
    2 – exercise 2

    Lift both legs and bend your knees to right angle
    Lift your upper torso to contract abdominal muscles and hold both knees
    Hold still for 3 seconds

    Return to the starting position" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" />
        </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

    <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: @Dawid - You'll some sort of gesture and/or scroll support.

Comment: Your scrollviewer is in the wrong place.  Look at my example.  The ScrollViewer should be *in* your contentpanel, not surrounding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Make sure to put your ScrollViewer *in* your ContentPanel's grid, not around it.**

*Edit:  here's where you need to change your code*

```
   <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
```

Your code should be:

```
   <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ScrollViewer>
```

**Sample below shows how it should work**

Do you maybe have your scrollviewer in the wrong grid?  I just tried this, and it gives me a scrolling textblock.

A couple things to make sure of.

- Your ScrollViewer should bein the Grid that is usually named "ContentPanel".
- You will need to specify how it should treat overflow text.  This is done via the `TextWrapping` attribute.

```xml
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="StackoWPF.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <TextBlock Height="2000" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                        One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: ok, scrollviewer works ;) So now, how can i see the rest of the screen? And about the text, it is wrapped, I set it in properties, but it's still in single line

Answer (score 0):

Robaticus has already answered most of it.
But, if you want linebreaks and formatting in your textblock(which you seem to need), refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165439/how-to-see-the-rest-of-screen-visual-studio-phone/10222749#10222749).

You have posted a similar question which I have answered.