# How to see the rest of screen visual studio phone

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Tell me how can i see the rest of the screen in my xaml? I added text block with height 2000 pixels, how can I see the rest?The second problem is, in my XAML my text is beautifully e.g. centered... But in emulator it's everything in single line.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="Excercises.Weider_s_six"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF1FB0DB">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Weider's six" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" FontSize="64" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer>
                <TextBlock Height="2000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="TextBlock1" Text="Weider 6 pack Training is a perfect exercise for flat stomach.
    This easy training programme has many advantages.
    It's perfect for beginners and for experts – exercises are easy and begin with the basic level, so every beginner can use them but they get more complicated pretty fast so advanced sportsmen can also be interested in them.
    It helps not only carve your muscles but also burn fat – during the exercise you not only use your abdominal rectus but you also move your legs and arms. It is also because W6 puts pressure on the number of repetitions. It carves your muscles but also burns fat. You can train W6 for about 40 minutes without taking any breaks – you use up all glycogen in blood and start burning the fat.
    It is easy – it is a really easy training set which you can train almost anywhere. All you need is flat ground.
    It gives excellent results – if you want to have a flat stomach W6 is designed just for you. You can see the first effects after just a week and after a whole series it is really impressive.
    How to do Weider 6

    Starting Position

    Lay flat on the ground, hands along the body.
    1 – exercise 1

    Lift your right leg and bend your knee to right angle angle
    Lift your upper torso to contract abdominal muscles and hold the lifted knee with your hands.
    Hold still for 3 seconds.
    Return to the starting position.
    Repeat the exercise with the other leg
    2 – exercise 2

    Lift both legs and bend your knees to right angle
    Lift your upper torso to contract abdominal muscles and hold both knees
    Hold still for 3 seconds

    Return to the starting position" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" />
        </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>

    <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to see the rest of screen and add more text visual studio phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164611/how-to-see-the-rest-of-screen-and-add-more-text-visual-studio-phone)

Comment: I didn't get help for the other questions. Just for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, include your textblock inside a scrollviewer and set its `Width` and `Height` to `Auto`.

Then, set `TextWrapping="Wrap"` in your textblock XAML and set `TextAlignment` property of textblock to required value to get required alignment.

And if you want formatted text, you can use something like this:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap">
<LineBreak/>
<Run Foreground="Maroon" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="40">
Some text 1
</Run>
<LineBreak/>
<Run text="Some Text 2"/>
<LineBreak/>
</TextBlock>
```

The `<LineBreak/>` corresponds to new line.

I think this will solve your all problems.

For further info, please refer [this](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/Working_with_Text_on_the_Windows_Phone).